# What does uses-feature android.hardware.gamepad and android:required=true do for non-android TV devices?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tv, gamepad

I'm developing a game which requires a gamepad if run on an Android-TV device.
However, if run on a regular phone/pad it does not require a gamepad.

I would like to specify in the manifest that a gamepad is only required on Android-TV devices?

The only option I have seem to be `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="true"/>`, does this affect regular phones/tablets?

Comment: You can check that by publishing a new APK and checking the device support in the store. Normally, Google Play will warn you when you're reducing the number of supported devices with the new APK. If it turns out that this tag affects phones as well, you can work around it by creating two flavors of the app - in the flavor for phones you can remove this particular tag from the manifest. Then you publish both APKs, and each type of device will get the appropriate one. Beware that the versionCode of each of the builds should be carefully chosen (it matters which has the higher number, check docs)